# How to call a get on schema endpoint with CORS in EVE?

Tags: python, eve

In my EVE configuration i have defined `SCHEMA_ENDPOINT='schema'` so that when i perform a get at `api_root/schema/resource` i get the schema for that resource. I also have `X_DOMAINS='*'` so that when I call a get on `api_root/resource/item` I get the item that I called for when calling my API from any domain. These both work separately now.

However, if I call `api_root/schema/resource` or even just `api_root/schema`, which would give me the schema for all of my resources, with CORS, which sends the `OPTIONS` preflight request, it fails on the preflight request. So when I make an ajax call on a different domain than the one the API is hosted on I get this error message in chrome:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.dev:5000/v1/schema/resource. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://test.dev:5002' is therefore not allowed access.`

Now I'm not having this problem with any other calls which use CORS. Like I said, I do not have this problem when calling `api_root/resource`. So I don't think it's a client side issue. Is there some sort of server side implementation I could do to get the schema endpoint working with CORS?

**UPDATE:**

So the problem is when sending `OPTIONS` and not `GET`. For example:

```
$ curl -I -X OPTIONS  -H "Origin: test.com" 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/schema/order' --verbose
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> OPTIONS /v1/schema/order HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://test.com
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Allow: HEAD, OPTIONS, GET
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Eve/0.6.2.dev0 Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.6
< Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 16:57:39 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested `SCHEMA_ENDPOINT` with CORS and everything seems to be working as expected. In my settings I have:

```
X_DOMAINS = '*'
SCHEMA_ENDPOINT = 'schema'
```

My pre-flight request:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://test.com" --verbose http://localhost:5000/schema

> GET /schema/contacts HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://test.com

< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://test.com
< Vary: Origin
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, OPTIONS, GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Max-Age: 21600
< Server: Eve/0.6.2.dev0 Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.8
```

Same happens with `/schema/resource`. Please note that `-Headers` are empty because in my test I did not set any `X_HEADERS` or `X_EXPOSE_HEADERS`.

EDIT: after your update I see that the issue is (was) with `OPTIONS`. It's been fixed upstream and will be released with v0.6.2.

Comment: This works for me too, however the problem is when sending the `OPTIONS` not the `GET`. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @SirNeuman it's been fixed upstream - answer updated. Thanks.